# LoopBack object mapping and change propagation

Tags: orm, loopbackjs, data-mapping

I'm new to loopback and I'm working on a project with NodeJs, Loopback and db Oracle.

I've already configured basically everything, but I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to have something like SQLAlchemy's merge function that for every change in a loopback object automatically (or manually with a flush or something) updates/inserts/deletes from the correct table on the db.

If not, do you know any other framework that does it?

Thank you

Comment: you mean something like [this](https://github.com/fullcube/loopback-ds-changed-mixin) for mongodb? What db you are using? Mongo or SQL or else?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I'm using Oracle as a db.
Let me give you an example: let's say I have a table on the Oracle db.
I have created the LoopBack model for that table.
When I retrieve the values of that table I save them in an object.
I want to bind that object to the db so that by changing one of the values of the object, an update to the db is automatically fired and if I add or delete an entry in the object, that add or delete is automatically done also on the db without having to write a function for every single possible scenario.
Can it be done with LoopBack?